# Making a bot work simultaneously on different Guilds/Servers - discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I've been trying to get a discord bot to work, it's a music bot but I need help to get through this phase of it.
I don't know how can I make the bot work on different servers simultaneously, by that I mean playing music simultaneously and independently on different servers.

```js
   case 'play':
      // Get the voice channel where the author of the message is in
      const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel;

      // Fetch the argument of the /play command
      const url = options.getString('url');

      if (!voiceChannel) {
        return interaction.reply('*Error:* `You need to be in a voice channel`');
      }

      // Check if the value given is a link
      else if (!url.startsWith('http')) {
        const Erro = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor(0xD93232)
          .setTitle(':no_entry: | Syntax error')
          .setDescription('You need to specify a link inside the ***url*** field')
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter({ text: 'Whisper' });
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [Erro] });
        return;
      }

      try {
        // Information
        const videoInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
        const videoTitle = videoInfo.videoDetails.title;
        const videoDuration = formatDuration(videoInfo.videoDetails.lengthSeconds);
        const publishDate = new Date(Date.parse(videoInfo.videoDetails.publishDate));
        const day = publishDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const month = (publishDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const year = publishDate.getFullYear();
        const publishedAt = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;

        if (connection) {
          // In case there is a song already playing
          queue.push({ url: url, title: videoTitle });

          // Inform the user that the song is added to the queue
          const queueEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0xEDEBDE)
            .addFields(
              { name: ' ', value: `:notes:   [${videoTitle}](${url})` }
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({ text: 'Song added to the queue' });
          interaction.reply({ embeds: [queueEmbed] });

        } else {
          // Start playing a song 
          
          queue.push({ url: url, title: videoTitle }); // Adds a song to the queue (url & title)

          // Make the connection to the voice channel
          connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
          });

          voiceConnections.set(connection.guildId, connection);

          console.log(voiceConnections);

          // Create or update the connection to make the song play
          const stream = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
          const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
          audioPlayer.play(resource);
          connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);

          // Inform the user that the song started playing
          const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0xEDEBDE)
            .addFields(
              { name: ' ', value: `:notes:   [${videoTitle}](${url})` },
              { name: '***Lenght***', value: videoDuration, inline: true },
              { name: '***\u200B***', value: '\u200B', inline: true },
              { name: '***Date of release***', value: publishedAt, inline: true }
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({ text: 'Now playing' });
          await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });

        }
```

I have tried to do it with the Map() function but no success with it.

Comment: Every player instance should be unique and independent from eachother, ensure you're not reassigning a player over and over. `Array.map()` modifies each element in an array and returns it as a new array, so I'm not exactly sure how the function would relate to unique player instances